# Doubt in Cesàro's theorem

Tags: real-analysis

If sequences $a_n  \to a ,\: b_n \to b$, then sequence $\frac{a_1b_n+a_2b_{n-1}+a_3b_{n-2}+\ldots +a_nb_1}{n}\to ab$.

I did it in following way

$$\frac{a_1b_n+a_2b_{n-1}+a_3b_{n-2}+\ldots +a_nb_1}{n} \to \frac{a(b_1+b_2+\ldots +b_n)}{n} \to ab $$ as we know that if $x_n \to x \implies \dfrac{x_1+x_2+\ldots +x_n}{n} \to x$

Is this something wrong?
But in my textbook, he took $a_n = a+\alpha_n, $ here $\alpha_n \to 0$ and then subsituted in above to get $ab$.

Comment: How could there still be $n$ in your expression after you let $n$ go to infinity? It does not make sense.

Comment: Ok it has to be applied at 1 go right. not in steps. Got it . thnks